# how to edit relationship fields in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, relationships

can we edit relationship fields in salesforce, like editing account name in opportunity details
page without navigating to account tab. If anyone has implemented using visualforce page, please post the code.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about appears to be "Can I edit a related record from the compact layout that appears when I hover over a relationship field?"

The answer to that is no. The compact layout is only for display.

I suspect that with enough effort, you could replicate the functionality of compact layouts (and add inline editing), but it's unlikely that the effort required would be worth it.

Training your users to use the middle-click on their mice (on Windows/Linux) to open the parent record in a new tab is likely a much easier and cheaper solution.